# Why isn't $1 + x + x^2 \dots = \frac{1}{1-x}$?

Tags: generating-functions, geometric-series

In [example 8.1 of "Combinatorics and Discrete Mathematics"](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Combinatorics_and_Discrete_Mathematics/Applied_Combinatorics_(Keller_and_Trotter)/08%3A_Generating_Functions/8.01%3A_Basic_Notation_and_Terminology), we consider the generating function:
$$ F(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n.$$
We find that
$$(1 + x + x^2 + \dots) - x(1 + x + x^2 + \dots) = 1,$$
which implies that
$$(1-x)F(x) = 1.$$
Finally getting
$$F(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}.$$
Now, the series only converges when $x < 1$. But in the rewriting steps that we just used, we didn't actually use any calculus, or any other techniques which make this restriction clear. So I would think that $F(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ as long as you don't divide by zero.

But this is obviously not the case, since the sum clearly diverges. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Welcome into the realm of [Formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series)!

Comment: The problem is in the first step, you assume you can open the brackets and cancel terms as if you are dealing with a finite sum.

Comment: If you are *not* using Calculus, then what does $1+x+x^2+\cdots$ mean?

Comment: See, it is all about dots: $\dots$ The expression with dots is a _tricky_ one. Sometimes it makes sense, and sometimes it doesn't. As logic teaches us, from nonsense you can deduce anything.

Comment: You don't seem to have been reading your text carefully. It says: "The word “function” is put in quotes as we do not necessarily care about substituting a value of  x
  and obtaining a specific value for  F(x)
 . In other words, we consider  F(x)
  as a formal power series and frequently ignore issues of convergence." and "we multiply formal power series just like we multiply polynomials" (they give a more formal definition below that example). Whence their "we can justify the expression$$\frac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+\dots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$ *without any calculus techniques*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But in the rewriting steps that we just used, we didn't actually use any calculus

On the contrary, you did use calculus, you just hid it in the symbol "$\dots$". What does that symbol really mean? Well, in general, when we write

$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots$$ what we really mean is $$\lim_{N\to\infty}(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_N)$$

and **there** is your calculus! Limits!

When operating with limits, you need to be very careful. In particular, the equation $$(1 + x + x^2 + \dots) - x(1 + x + x^2 + \dots) = 1$$ is a statement about limits, and is only valid if $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 4):

On the one hand, when $x$ is a real number, $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$ only makes sense when $|x|<1$.

On the other hand, in a [ring of formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) $R[[x]]$, the polynomial $1-x$ has an inverse and it's $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$. No convergence enters here.